# Passing a different function into the same iteration loop (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, loops, class, collections

My overall goal is to translate an Excel based financial model into VBA. The financial model has a number of scenarios (e.g. 3) and development types (e.g. 3 - residential, commercial, industrial). There are two components of the model - revenue and costs - at present but my solution needs to be massively scalable.

The revenue calculation will be the same for each of the nine instances but the inputs will change. I am taking the inputs from the workbook and placing them in collections. I add the result of the calculation to another collection. The costs calculation will be different but will use the exact same iteration loops.

What I'm trying to do is write the iteration code once but pass a different calculation to the loop. I've done it as follows by coding the formula in a Class Object and then passing the Class Object into a function. Please see below a sandbox example.

```
' Passing different classes into iteration loop
Sub Main()

Dim clsAdd As CAdd
Dim colAdd As Collection
Set clsAdd = New CAdd
Set colAdd = New Collection
Set colAdd = Iteration(clsAdd)

Dim clsMul As CMult
Dim colMul As Collection
Set clsMul = New CMult
Set colMul = New Collection
Set colMul = Iteration(clsMul)

End Sub
```

```
' Same iteration loop required for different calculations
Function Iteration(ByRef colClass As Object) As Collection

Dim varArray01() As Variant
Dim varArray02() As Variant

Dim itA As Integer

Set Iteration = New Collection

varArray01 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
varArray02 = Array(11, 12, 13, 14)

For itA = 0 To UBound(varArray01)
    Iteration.Add colClass.ICalculation_Calculation(varArray01(itA), varArray02(itA))
Next itA

End Function
```

```
'Add Class
Public Function Calculation(ByVal intA As Integer, ByVal intB As Integer) As Integer
    Calculation = intA + intB
End Function
```

```
'Multiply Class
Public Function Calculation(ByVal intA As Integer, ByVal intB As Integer) As Integer
    Calculation = intA * intB
End Function
```

Although this works, I feel that there must be a better solution than creating a new Class Object for each formula I want because every formula must be calculated using the a function called 'Calculation'. Your suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: It looks I did not get you reading the question and I am not able to better understand what you mean, even now... Don't you need writing a different `Calculation` function for each of the three cases? If yes, why writing them in different classes? You can use `Select Case` using string key, let us say `devType` and call the appropriate function according to (only) three cases: "res", "com", "ind"... Why do you need/like/want using the same `Calcualation` function? If you insist, create such a unique function, but use `Select Case` inside it, calling with `devtType` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently already have an interface defined for your calculation classes.  Just change the parameter of `Iteration` to take the interface directly.

You have implemented the [Command](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) design pattern.  Small, single purpose Command objects (your CAdd and CMult) are (IMO) good design..I wouldn't try to convince you to take a different approach.

```
    ' Same iteration loop required for different calculations
    Function Iteration(ByRef calculator As ICalculation) As Collection

    Dim varArray01() As Variant
    Dim varArray02() As Variant

    Dim itA As Integer

    Set Iteration = New Collection

    varArray01 = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
    varArray02 = Array(11, 12, 13, 14)

    For itA = 0 To UBound(varArray01)
        Iteration.Add calculator.Calculation(varArray01(itA), varArray02(itA))
    Next itA

    End Function
```

Sub Main becomes:

```
    ' Passing different classes into iteration loop
    Sub Main()

    Dim colAdd As Collection
    Set colAdd = Iteration(New CAdd)

    Dim colMul As Collection
    Set colMul = Iteration(New CMult)

    End Sub
```

If creating several small, 'stateless' classes is not the kind of solution you are looking for, then the Command pattern can also be implemented using a single Class that contains a minimal amount of 'state'.

using a class like `Calculator` below:

```
    Option Explicit

    Implements ICalculation

    Public Enum CalcID
        Add
        Multiply
    End Enum

    Private mCalculationID As CalcID

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        mCalculationID = Add
    End Sub


    Public Property Get CalculationID() As CalcID
        CalculationID = mCalculationID
    End Property

    Public Property Let CalculationID(ByVal RHS As CalcID)
        Select Case RHS
            Case Add, Multiply
                mCalculationID = RHS
            Case Else
                Err.Raise -1, "Invalid calculationID: " & CStr(RHS)
        End Select
    End Property

    Private Function ICalculation_Calculation(ByVal intA As Integer, ByVal intB As Integer) As Integer
        Select Case mCalculationID
            Case Multiply
                ICalculation_Calculation = intA * intB
            Case Add
                ICalculation_Calculation = intA + intB
            Case Else
                'Raise an error
        End Select
    End Function
```

Now you have one calculator class to manage...and the calling module(s) are responsible for managing the calculator's configuration.  The `Main` subroutine changes slightly and the `Iteration` function remains unchanged.

```
    Sub Main()

        Dim calc As Calculator
        Set calc = New Calculator
        
        calc.CalculationID = CalcID.Add

        Dim colAdd As Collection
        Set colAdd = Iteration(calc)

        calc.CalculationID = CalcID.Multiply

        Dim colMul As Collection
        Set colMul = Iteration(calc)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks BZngr. Maybe what I was actually looking for was the reassurance that I was following good practice. I may very well have quite a few classes by the end of this project but it sounds like that isn't a problem.